# what is the difference between connecting h2 by http://localhost:8080/h2-console vs clicking h2 icon

Tags: jpa, h2

well i was confused because i coudn't find tables in DB. i used JPA and saw DDL queries.. i figured this problem by connecting h2 by requesting url "http://localhost:8080/h2-console"

the reason i failed was because i tried to connect h2 by clicking h2 icon like this.[image]

i searched a lot but coudn't figure out the reason of issue. what is the difference between these two ways of connecting h2. can you guys tell me the reason of issue related with difference?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a separate H2 Server process and its icon in the system tray opens a H2 Console attached to the server, and you also have an embedded H2 Console servlet in your application. They look similar, but they aren't related to each other.

If your application uses an **embedded** persistent or in-memory database, you don't need that server process, it isn't used by application.

But if your application uses a JDBC connection URL like `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/…` or `jdbc:h2:ssl://localhost/…`, you need that separate server.